# Using Liquid in Rails assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, liquid

I'm using Liquid in my CSS. For example, I have `test.css.liquid` which contains:

`body {
      background: {{ 'red' }};
    }`

When I run `rake assets:precompile`, it's not `test.css` that's compiled but still `test.css.liquid` and the Liquid code isn't parsed.

Sprockets uses Tilt which has a Liquid parser by default. I have Liquid enabled on my site.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It is bad idea to rename the manifest file `application.css`. You can include assets by requiring it in the manifest file , like this :

```
*= require your_styles
```

and in case you've initiated the `liquid` engine , it should be OK.

Comment: Hey Qumara, thanks for the answer. I was probably unclear, I'm making a theme with files in app/themes/<name> and assets in this directory under assets/. My application.css is not a manifest, it actually contains all the styles. It has a few lines containing Liquid code though, which is why it needs to be parsed. I want to use the asset pipeline so that it get parsed and uploaded to S3 automatically.

Comment: I think you cannot make `application.css` not-manifest file if you choose to rely on asset-pipeline. Could you update your question with file structure of your app ?

Comment: I've updated my question. I don't think the naming of the file has anything to do with it. The only difference between `application.css` and any other name is that `application.css` is compiled by default without the need to add it to `config.assets.precompile`.

Comment: It seems [this Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) is going to help you with asset-pipeline.

Comment: Thanks, the part that could be useful http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#making-your-library-or-gem-a-pre-processor is TODO. It refers to Tilt though and I think it should work out of the box. Anyhow, forget about the whole theme thing, that's confusing and doesn't bring anything to the table. I've updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: Cool , that's completely different question :) Nothing wrong if you create a new question.

Comment: That really was my original question... just badly put together the first time.